# Apache Freemarker Template module for perl

Tags: perl, templates, expression, freemarker

i wanna evaluate freemarker template expression in perl, do we have any module which supports it ?. Thank you.

Comment: [Searching CPAN for "freemarker"](https://metacpan.org/search?size=20&q=freemarker) didn't return anything. So probably not.

Comment: Thanks Dave. there is no module found.

Comment: Yes. That's what I said.

Answer (score 2):

You can

- call `fmpp` as a child process (e.g. with [`IPC::System::Simple`](http://p3rl.org/IPC::System::Simple))
- or call the Java library with [`Inline::Java`](http://p3rl.org/Inline::Java).

Comment: Hi Daxim, thanks for your response, can i get sample snippet code using fmpp, for freemarker template ?

Comment: Yes sir, it's working, tried with Inline::Java, thank you so much. Do we need to bind perl Hash ref to pass java as a HashMap ? any code or link would be help full.

Comment: @goutham, [open a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for that.

Comment: Ok Daxim, link for the same, [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144163/how-do-we-bind-perl-hash-reference-to-java-hash-map/58144699#58144699]

Answer (score 0):

FreeMarker only has Java implementation. As it's among the more complex template languages, it's unlikely that it will be ported to other platforms.