# How do we bind perl hash reference to java hash map

Tags: java, perl

I am using [Inline::Java](https://metacpan.org/pod/Inline::Java) in Perl, and I need to pass a hash to a Java method.

I have tried the following code:

```
my $obj = new Pod_101() ;
my %data = ('input' => 45, 'Lisa' => 30, 'Kumar' => 40);
my $val = $obj->evaluate(\%data, "\${input*12}");
```

It results in the following error:

> Can't convert HASH(0x556322c62368) to object java.util.Map at
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.26/Inline/Java/Object.pm line 107.

Comment: How is `evaluate()` defined?

Comment: Seems like passing hashes is not supported, but passing arrays are. So you could try pass the hash as an array to Java?

Comment: public String evaluate(Map results, String s) {
 String expression = s;
 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();

 try {
  System.out.println(results);
  expression = "<#setting number_format=\"##.##\">\n" + expression;
  
  Template expressionTemplate = new Template("expression", new  StringReader(expression), new Configuration());

 expressionTemplate.process(results, writer);
 } catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
 }

 return writer.toString();

     }

Answer (score 2):

It seems like passing Perl hashes to Java is not directly supported.
Here is an example of how you can work around the issue by passing the hash keys and values as arrays instead:

```
use Inline Java => <<'END' ;
   import java.util.* ;

   class Pod_101 {
      public Pod_101() {
      }

      public HashMap get_hash (String keys[], Integer vals[] ){
         HashMap<String, Integer> hash = new HashMap<>() ;
         for(int i= 0; i < keys.length; i++){
             hash.put(keys[i], vals[i]);
         }
         return hash;
      }
      public Integer evaluate(HashMap<String, Integer> h, String foo){
          return h.get("input") ;
      }
   }
END

my $obj = Pod_101->new() ;
my %data = ('input' => 45, 'Lisa' => 30, 'Kumar' => 40);
my $h = $obj->get_hash( [keys %data], [values %data]) ;
my $val = $obj->evaluate($h, "\${input*12}");
print "$val\n";
```

**Output**:

```
45
```

Comment: Thanks  Håkon Hægland, it is working as you suggested.